# Automatic folding with dosini files in neovim on Linux

Tags: neovim

I have config files in the [DOS INI format](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Dosini_files).

As explained in the link above, to make vim automatically fold the DOS INI files by section, I need to create a new file ~/.vim/after/syntax/dosini.vim
with:

```
syn region dosiniSection start="^\[" end="\(\n\+\[\)\@=" contains=dosiniLabel,dosiniHeader,dosiniComment keepend fold
setlocal foldmethod=syntax
" Following opens all folds (remove line to start with folds closed).
setlocal foldlevel=20
```

I did exactly that and it does not work with neovim (folders after/syntax did not exist, I had to create them).

Is the location of the after/syntax folders different in neovim than in vim? Or is the problem somewhere else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is the location of the after/syntax folders different in neovim than in vim?

Yes. Nvim follows the [XDG Base Directory Specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html).

What `~/.vim` is to Vim, is `~/.config/nvim` to Nvim.

So, either create `~/.config/nvim/after/syntax/dosini.vim` or, do what most people do and, create a symlink `~/.config/nvim` that points to `~/.vim`.

If you also want to share the vimrc between both then create a symlink `~/.config/init.vim` that points to your `~/.vim/vimrc` (or `~/.vimrc`).